# Simple Multi-Layer Zoom (map) Tiles in HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a simple multi-layer zoom map with tiles in JavaScript (similar to Google Maps --- the more you zoom in the more details you see). I don't want to use the Google Maps API because I am creating fictional treasure maps.

I only want 2 zoom levels --- zoomed out and zoomed in. I made 500 pixel by 500 pixel tiles. The zoomed out view uses only one tile and the zoomed in view uses 4 tiles. The viewable area for the tiles is 75 pixels by 75 pixels (window). In both views the user can pan.

Below are both views:

[image: Zoomed In View]

[image: Zoomed Out View]

I'm having a tough time getting started. I would like to do this in HTML / CSS / JavaScript. I found something called Polymaps (http://polymaps.org) which seems to offer what I want but with a lot of extra features. There's no tutorial on creating a map with custom tiles. Is this possible to easily do with JavaScript? Any recommendations on what to use?

Comment: What's inside your map? Is it SVG graphics or pure image? What kind of actions do you want it to support?

Comment: SVG. Zoom in, zoom out, and panning. Multi touch zoom and panning on Android and iOS would be great but I would be happy just to get started.

Comment: @user1822824 I wonder if you have found a solution to your problem. I am doing the same thing, and could use your help

Answer (score 1):

Try [SVGPan library](http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/) :

The SVGPan library features:

- Panning (pan à la Google maps) (click on the white background and
  pan)
- Zooming (using the mouse wheel)
- Element dragging (click on a drawing element and drag it somewhere
  else)
- Combinations of the above like zooming while dragging

[demo](http://www.cyberz.org/projects/SVGPan/tiger.svg)

Comment: This is good but I need 2 zoom layers. As the user zooms in more details should show. Like Google maps, as you zoom in you start to see streets, etc.

Comment: I think you have to handle the SVG data (content) loading in your code, according to the mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three options for implementing zoomable, multi-resolution images:

- Simple image pan/zoom library:
  [CanvasZoom](http://www.akademy.co.uk/software/canvaszoom/)
- Use Google Maps API and supply your own tiles. See: [Mike Couturier's
  Zoomable Image
  examples](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html)
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) is an extensive, open-source
  mapping library that supports custom tile layers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these js libs will serve the purpose:

- https://github.com/hackyon/jQuery-Tiles: Very like google maps, but waaay simpler
- http://labs.webcodingstudio.com/tilezoom/index.html: This one is a bit different, as it's less for maps and more for general images with specific POIs, but definitely can be used for maps.

I'm using [jQuery-Tiles](https://github.com/hackyon/jQuery-Tiles) to display a fantasy map for a personal/fun project.